# Не исчезает ошибка чтения расширения файла в nodeJs

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const server = http.createServer((req, res) =>  {
let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public',  req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : req.url)
const ext = path.extname(filePath)

let contentType =  'text/html'
switch(ext){
    case '.css':
        contentType = 'text/css'
        break
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript'
            break
            default:
                 contentType ='text/html'
}
if (!ext){
    filePath +='.html   '
}
console.log(filePath)
fs.readFile(filePath, (err,content) =>{
    if (err){
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'error404.html'), (err,data) =>{
if (err){
res.writeHead(500)
res.end('lol')
} else {
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
})
res.end(data)
      }
     })
        } else {
         res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-type': contentType
        })
        res.end(content)
    }
})


   })
    server.listen(3000, () =>{
    console.log('bla-bla-bla...')
 })
```

> Переменная ext проверяет расширение файла и заменяется по ситуации. Следовательно на хосте исчезает ошибка из-за отсутствия расширения. Вроде все написал правильно, а ошибка  не исчезает. Ошибок в терминале нет. Если нужно укажу html файлы.

Comment: `filePath +='.html   '` — тут точно нужно столько пробелов?

Comment: Ну и вообще, какая ошибка? Где?

Comment: Блин, я в шоке. Реально из-за пробелов. Какой же он чувствительный.

Comment: ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: Не уместный смайлик, когда человек первый день занимается nodeJS